# react-native axios php network error only android

Tags: php, react-native, axios

I am a beginner in react native I work with expo I make a very simple request to a local server in php which is sent send a message the problem is that when I make the request on the web interface it works but when I do it via my android I receive a errorerror network

```
enter code here
await  axios.get('http://localhost/api/message.php')
          

            .then((response) => console.log(response))
            // console.log(r)
            
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // console.error("first",error.message);
                console.log("second", error.message)
                // alert("error")
            });
    }
php code 

<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(
    'message' => 'feed back du serveur'
))


?>
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are receiving?

Comment: Network Error but but on the web application it works

Comment: What network error? I am sure you are seeing this error in it's entirety somewhere. Edit your question and paste it there. Otherwise, it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: I am use axios, when I run my app in the computer this run but when I run my app with expo I received only  "network error " (I am log " error mesage") ? I code in react native and it's the same code that compiles for both

Comment: thank you all its arranging
I develop locally with expo so when my server side is also locally it sends me a network error
after putting this on my amazon server its working